# SVN Update * question

Tags: svn, macos

I'm using mac os x and would like to use the command svn update *. it works but only updates some of the sub folders. how can i get this to happen recursively?

Comment: Why do you think that not all directories has been updated?

Answer (score 2):

it is recursive by default,
$ svn update

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.ref.svn.c.update.html